# Generic stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to write a stored procedure that creates a record in a table and update another using this inserted record.

The problem is, I must to do this for all tables in my database.

E.g.

I have these four tables:

```
Person;
Address;
Question;
User;
```

And another table:

```
TimeStampRegistry
```

This last table must to create a record for each record of each table and link it to another table registry. When I insert a record in `Person`, I must to insert another in `TimeStampRegistry`, and link both records.

Then, my question is: how can I control, using only one stored procedure the inserts or updates of all tables in my database?

Comment: You can create one store procedure to do what you need and then call it using a trigger - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx. You could have a `source` input parameter that will be different for each procedure call among the triggers.

Comment: If you want to insert something into `TimeStampRegistry` whenever there's an insert into the other tables, you should look at an INSERT **trigger** (not a stored procedure)

Answer (score 1):

Create one single SP and pass to it an int 
parameter which denotes the table name.

For example:
1 - Person;
2 - Address;
3 - Question;
4 - User.

Then code some IF-ELSE logic in your SP.

Or ... just pass the table name and build 
your SQL statements dynamically.

But if the table schemas differ a lot, I don't 
think you can do this in a generic, nice way.